# How do I list the absolute path of running processes?

Tags: linux, perl

I had a problem recently, where a perl script was consuming server resources. I found out it was a perl script by using "top". But it didn't give the path to the script. Nor did "ps".

Is it possible to get the paths to currently running perl scripts? If so, how?

Clarification : i don't need the path to the perl binary, *i need the path to the perl script that binary is currently executing*.

Comment: What options did you use with ps? ps -ef should give you the full path to what is running.

Comment: Dupe of http://superuser.com/questions/103309/how-can-i-know-the-absolute-path-of-a-running-process, where it's better asked anyway.

Comment: I would disagree this is a dupe of that question, because the absolute path to the running process in this case would be the path to perl binary. I need to know the path to the script that the perl binary is currently executing. I have probably not written the question clear enough..

Answer (score 1):

First get the pid from `ps aux` or `ps -ef` (it's the second column). Suppose it's 42. Then do (as root):

```
ls -l /proc/42/exe
```

To get a list automatically you can use something like this:

```
for pid in `ps auxwww | grep perl | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`; do ls -l /proc/$pid/exe; done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always try to locate the PL file on your filesystem (using *find*, *locate*, etc). If you have multiple PL files with the same name, you'd have to dig deeper: something like [dstat](http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/dstat/), if available for your distro, could be a good option.